# Where is IntelliJ IDEA's File Structure action implemented?

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-plugin

I'm writing an IntelliJ plugin, and I've somehow broken the file structure navigation (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F12</kbd>). I want to debug the navigation action, but I can't find where it's implemented.

More generally, how do I step through the code that runs when I choose a command from the menu in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of searching and debugging, I found the code that runs when you select an item from the file structure. It's in [`PyStructureViewElement.navigate()`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/1ef68923b2a9475d80173155d83bb7c1872694aa/python/src/com/jetbrains/python/structureView/PyStructureViewElement.java#L86-L91).

Once I found that, I was able to walk up the stack to [`ActionUtil.performActionDumbAware()`](https://github.com/JetBrains/intellij-community/blob/171.4694/platform/platform-api/src/com/intellij/openapi/actionSystem/ex/ActionUtil.java#L215). That's a good place to put a breakpoint when you want to find the code for some other menu item or command. Then you can either look at the class of the action object or step into `action.actionPerformed()`. I found that sometimes, I had to set a pass count on the breakpoint so it didn't break until I got the action I was interested in.